# Updating listview by API best practice

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code which call API to get the xml items. 
and list view is updated by article.

For now after change the variable of listview I called setState() once.

However as running this code. 
setState() is called infinitely, and keep updating.

How should I solve or what is the best practice??

```
class Article{
  String title;
  String url;
  Article() {}
}
List<Article> articles = [];

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;


  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _callApi() async{
      final response = await http.get('http://localhost/mamasoku/web/app_dev.php/api/byLatest/1/10');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        var document = xml.parse(response.body);
        var items = document.findAllElements('item');
        print("item number:" + items.length.toString());
        items.forEach((var item) {
          var a = Article();
          a.title = item.findElements('title').single.text;
          a.url = item.findElements('url').single.text;
          articles.add(a);
        });
        setState(() => {});
      }
    }
    _callApi();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BodyLayout(), 
    );
  }
}
class BodyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _myListView(context);
  }
}
 Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {


      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: articles.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(articles[index].title),
          );
        },
      );
    }

void onTapped(var index) {
  print(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why setState() is called infinitely is setState() will call the build(BuildContext context) method.

so,you should remove setState() from build(BuildContext context) method,and move _callApi() method to initState()，

like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class Article {
  String title;
  String url;

  Article() {}
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<Article> articles = [];

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _callApi();
  }

  void _callApi() async {
//    final response = await http
//        .get('http://localhost/mamasoku/web/app_dev.php/api/byLatest/1/10');
//    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
//      var document = xml.parse(response.body);
//      var items = document.findAllElements('item');
//      print("item number:" + items.length.toString());
//      items.forEach((var item) {
//        var a = Article();
//        a.title = item.findElements('title').single.text;
//        a.url = item.findElements('url').single.text;
//        articles.add(a);
//      });
//
//    }

  ///  Analog network request
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10)).then((data){
    articles.add(Article()..title="test1"..url="www.123.com");
    articles.add(Article()..title="test2"..url="www.123.com");
    articles.add(Article()..title="test3"..url="www.123.com");
    articles.add(Article()..title="test4"..url="www.123.com");
    setState(() => {});
  });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BodyLayout(articles),
    );
  }
}

class BodyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Article> articles;

  BodyLayout(this.articles);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: articles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(articles[index].title),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

void onTapped(var index) {
  print(index);
}
```

Comment: THank you very much , you hit perfectly my problem. This sample code is perfect and good to learn. I understood why setState is called infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a lot of changes to apply best practices here, you need separate the model, the api calls, the logic and the views and that way you can apply Single Responsibility pattern, also is recommendable use BloC pattern to separate the logic from the view and create a generic class to handle all the api calls so in the future when you need to do a similar call to the api you don't need to repeat the code (DRY pattern), maybe you need to apply more changes but for now with those changes should be enough is a lot of work but trust me it will help you to improve your app

Comment: thank you . I get used to other frameworks view /mode/ controller style already. But now I am struggling with flutter ....